# How does Trusteer Rapport protect a user when browsing a non-partner website?

Tags: security

Having installed and read Trusteer Rapport's FAQs regarding the level of protection, it states that **Rapport's access control policies are set by your bank** (http://www.trusteer.com/support/en/about-rapport - under How is Rapport different from my top-notch Internet Security suite?).

It also states that it protects a user when accessing websites such as Gmail, Yahoo, etc and I presume also websites such as SuperUser, etc if I select to protect my login details. However it is unclear how it protects the user if the control policies are set by an organization that is a partner of Trusteer and when the user browses to a site that is not a partner e.g. SuperUser.com?

Would anyone know how it works with non-partner websites as well as how much security is offered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See related question [What does Trusteer Rapport do?](https://superuser.com/questions/332012/what-does-trusteer-rapport-do)

I believe it checks that the server's IP-address is the same as when the non-partner website was first accessed (or talks to Trusteer home to verify this)

A few times it has popped up to warn me that I was typing data into a form on a non-protected website where the data was similar to data I'd previously entered into a form on a protected website and therefore that I might be a victim of phishing.

There is some information at http://www.trusteer.com/presentation-how-it-works and http://www.trusteer.com/product/technology but I don't know of an independent evaluation of the Rapport software that specifically discusses what identifiable or personal information Trusteer collect from users of Rapport, if any.

Comment: Thanks. I did read the question however it does tell me how for example it validates the IP address e.g. does it access a database, does it phone home, etc. If it does phone home, is this a security concern? Also what information does it provide to the sites I visit assuming it detects security vulnerabilities?

As for your comment in the second paragraph, does this mean it is storing your login details and if so again is this a security and privacy concern?

Comment: @peanutsMonkey: Those are good questions but I don't know the answers.  I did use a network sniffer and noticed that Rapport does contact the Trusteer site quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Were you able to tell what information was being sent back to Trusteer?